# Error in dist files Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

Hi everyone at stackoverflow, I'm trying to release my Angular 2 app but I'm having issues with the `dist` files. First what I do is:

- Clean the `node_modules` dir and remove the `package-lock.json`
- Run the `npm install` and then `npm update` commands
- After that I run the `ng build --prod` and everything is fine.

So, I check the `dist` folder and copy it to my server, and when I try to access it shows me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
>       at vendor.7bb6292ce7eeab342f9a.bundle.js:1
>       at e.invoke (polyfills.0963b44a58b5526cfab7.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.onInvoke (vendor.7bb6292ce7eeab342f9a.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.invoke (polyfills.0963b44a58b5526cfab7.bundle.js:1)
>       at r.run (polyfills.0963b44a58b5526cfab7.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.run (vendor.7bb6292ce7eeab342f9a.bundle.js:1)
>       at e._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (vendor.7bb6292ce7eeab342f9a.bundle.js:1)
>       at e.bootstrapModuleFactory (vendor.7bb6292ce7eeab342f9a.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.cDNt (main.e10f9a0cb71451c87757.bundle.js:1)
>       at n (inline.d31757e5f12d693ae92a.bundle.js:1)

I know is a library related issue because the minify is not working as intended, but I don't know which library is doing that since `ng serve` is working fine and showing no errors.

I don't know if there is some way to debug which library is doing this error or where it comes from.

This is what I get when I do the `ng build --prod` command. Also I included the `enableProdMode();`function already.

[image: capture]

## Update

Thanks everyone, the issue was that in my `app.module.ts`I had the `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` and it was an error because in an updated version is in `main.ts` now and not in the `app.module.ts` so I had this duplicated and now everything is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Try building your project with AOT: `ng build --prod --aot`. Maybe that will help identify which file the error is coming from?

Comment: Already tried with `--aot` too but without success I get the same error. So I don't have any clue where it comes from.

Comment: Just FYI .. the --prod already does aot. See the nice chart here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds

Comment: @DeborahK didn't realize this is the default. Last time I checked the docs I don't believe it was the default. Good to know!

Comment: That chart is very handy to keep on hand! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen the issue for this error here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5181 It suggests that it may be a problem with the platformBrowserDynamic setup in main.ts, especially if this app was started with an older/different version of Angular or the CLI.

My main.ts looks like this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```