# Getting cannot read property 'create' of undefined on production build

Tags: angular

My Angular 2 app's dev build is up and running on an s3 bucket, but when i build the same project to production everything seems like fine until i go to the browser, the only thing displaying is the background and nothing else happens, i just get from the browser console (safari, chrome and firefox):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
at vendor.d7172912c49a3cb3fd70.bundle.js:1
at e.invoke (polyfills.900aaf0d520c2ec873a7.bundle.js:1)
at Object.onInvoke (vendor.d7172912c49a3cb3fd70.bundle.js:1)
at e.invoke (polyfills.900aaf0d520c2ec873a7.bundle.js:1)
at r.run (polyfills.900aaf0d520c2ec873a7.bundle.js:1)
at t.run (vendor.d7172912c49a3cb3fd70.bundle.js:1)
at e._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (vendor.d7172912c49a3cb3fd70.bundle.js:1)
at e.bootstrapModuleFactory (vendor.d7172912c49a3cb3fd70.bundle.js:1)
at Object.cDNt (main.c6300516c42c7516e9d4.bundle.js:1)
at n (inline.b1cb35e1ce9c41e46cbe.bundle.js:1)
```

inside main.xx.bundle.js i see this

[image]

I'm really lost here, any help is appreciated. this is a similar [problem](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5181) like mine maybe you can get something out of there that i didn't :)

PS: i already tried:

```
ng build --prod
ng build --prod --aot
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
ng build -e=prod --prod --no-sourcemap --aot
```

this + dev build working made me realise it's not a problem with how i build the app

tried console.log in app.component since the background loaded but it isn't displaying either.

i don't get any other errors, i have checked other projects on GitHub to see how they setup their dev/prod environments and make sure i did it right.

I've probably tried most mainstream solutions.. question: could this be a backend's problem/endpoint/etc?

Comment: can you try `ng serve --prod` or `ng build --aot` it might give you a better description of the error

Comment: I started running the server with ng serve --prod after i realised it wasn't working on the bucket, and ng build --aot displays same message but with a nicer format! if you'd like me to do anything else just let me know i'm working on it right now

Comment: what is error log when you do `ng build --aot`

Comment: WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts -> src/app/app.module.ts -> src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/app.module.ts -> src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts -> src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: it is a dependency warning you are using a module inside another and then reusing it again like a in b and b i n a

Comment: Turn the aot off and see if it helps:
ng build --prod --aot=false

Comment: @YakovFain That works you're awesome! but doesn't turning AOT off affects my app's performance? Do you think fixing the circular dependecy  Rahul said will make my app AOT compatible?

Comment: Turning the aot off doesn't affect your app performance. It may slow down the initial rendering of the landing page if your app is large, but fixing the code to ensure it aot-compile is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. 
In my own case, the issue was that `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` 
was defined in main.ts and also in AppModule.

I solved my problem by deleting the duplicate in AppModule.
The answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827028/error-in-dist-files-angular-2) helped in solving my issue.